# How to prevent stackoverflow traffic from appearing in Google Analytics?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, google, hyperlinks

Hi, 
When developing sites I sometimes post links to sites I have problems with. I don't want this information to appear in google analytics, is there a way I can prevent the question from appearing in the direct traffic section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideas:

1. Post links through tinyurl or some other link obfuscation service? (you should probably include a disclaimer in the post about why you did this, otherwise the community might suspect your motives.)
2. Don't post clickable links, make them plain text?

Comment: Thanks, although the other answer was very useful, I still think this is probably the 100% safe way

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to exclude the traffic from `stackoverflow.com` using a custom filter in you Google Analytics configuration. On the main page, look for the "Filter Manager", which will take you to a screen like the one shown in the image below (sorry about the lack of freehand circles btw):

---

[image: Filter screen]

Comment: Thanks, I can accept this answer if it's the only way, however if I am not the admin of GA, is there anything I can do?

Comment: If you can inject JavaScript, maybe you could check `document.referrer` and decide whether or not to run the GA tracking script. Seems pretty dodgy, though.